# Angular directive: immediately access directive data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm still new to directives so bear with me. I have multiple views in my app. Now some, but not all, of these views use another partial view that consists of a few date/time and numeric input fields. We'll call it time.html. This time.html partial view has it's own controller complete with a set of functions for manipulating the data fields.

time.html:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="data.timeOptions" data-ng-value="true">Time Span
    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="data.timeOptions" data-ng-value="false">Ticker
    <fieldset data-ng-if="data.timeOptions">
        <label>Start:
            <input id="startDate"
                   type="date"
                   data-ng-model="data.startDate">
            <input id="startTime"
                   data-data.start-time
                   type="time"
                   data-ng-model="data.startTime">
        </label>
        <label>End:
            <input id="endDate"
                   type="date"
                   data-ng-model="data.endDate">
            <input id="endTime"
                   data-data.end-time
                   type="time"
                   data-ng-model="data.endTime">
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset data-ng-if="!data.timeOptions">
        <label>Ticker Interval (min):
            <input class="ticker"
                   type="number"
                   step="1"
                   data-ng-model="data.tkrIntrvl">
        </label>
        <label>Refresh every (s):
            <input class="ticker"
                   type="number"
                   step="1"
                   data-ng-model="data.refresh">
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

There are two different fieldsets here, separated with radio buttons. The first is a date/time fieldset, which consists of start date, start time, end date, and end time. The second is a numeric ticker fieldset which I won't go into details about, but just know it's there.
I wrote a very basic directive for adding this partial view to whatever views I need it in:

```
.directive("timeDirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'partials/time.html',
      controller: 'TimeCtrl',
      scope: false,
      transclude: false
    };
});
```

As an example, I add this directive to another view. We'll call it view1.html:

```
<div>
    <h1>View1</h1>
    <form name="form" novalidate>
        <div data-time-directive></div>
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.model1">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.model2">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.model3">
    <button data-ng-click="someFunction(data)">Do Things</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Now that the setup is out of the way, I'm having two issues

The first is that the date/time and numeric fields all need to be initialized to different values on each of the views that use them. If I initialize them in the TimeCtrl controller, then all views that use this directive will be initialized to the same date/time and ticker values. I need to initialize them on a view-by-view basis.

The second issue is similar. I need to immediately be able to access the date/time and ticker values after initializing them and store them in another $scope variable in the 'parent' controller of the directive. In this example case, it'd be view1.html's controller.

Something like this:

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
               //Initializing directive data fields
               $scope.data = [];
               $scope.data.tkrIntrvl = 10;
               $scope.data.refresh = 60;
               var ed = new Date();
               var dms = ed.getTime();
               var sd = new Date(dms - 1800000); //1,800,000ms = 30 min
               $scope.data.startDate = sd;
               $scope.data.endDate = ed;
               $scope.data.startTime = sd;
               $scope.data.endTime = ed;

               $scope.someOtherObject.startDate = $scope.data.startDate;
               $scope.someOtherObject.endDate = $scope.data.endDate; //etc..
```

}]);

Is what I'm looking for. Trying to define the directive's data fields in the "parents'" controllers like this doesn't work, but something like this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?  Something like <time-directive init-data="data" /> would pull your $scope.data into @initData in the Directive.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not actually sure how to define/use attributes like that on a directive. Would I need to add anything to my directive as well?

Comment: You'd need to define the scope to be able to receive the variable. Not to be rude, but this is all covered in the angularjs documentation for directives.

Comment: Yes, after reading @Shaun Scovil's comment and looking up the documentation a little more I fixed that initial issue I was having. However, I also route to this page (view1.html) using ui-router from another page (say view2.html). When I access view1.html this way, I try to immediately call a function in the directive template's controller from view1.html's controller and I get a "TypeError: [function] is not a function" error.

Comment: You shouldn't have access to a child directive's controller from the parent. If you want to provide such access push a callback into the directive from the parent and then have the child call it with a reference to the function, which can then be safely called.

Comment: I should be a little more specific. The function I'm trying to call, that is in the child directive's controller, is being called from another function within view1.html's controller, which you stated I shouldn't have access to. This kind of wrapper function is then called repeatedly at certain intervals using angular's $timeout. Also, this wrapper function is in an if statement. If the if condition returns true, the wrapper function is called. If false, the function is not called.

Comment: Don't use features that you have access to that you shouldn't. Instead, find ways to use them as intended/designed. You've discovered the reason--you can't always use them even if you occasionally find a loophole where you can. The only way I would suggest that you use these is if you dig through the code and figure out how it is that you can use things you shouldn't have access  to. If you can understand it, it's not a fluke.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Amy. After reading your and Shaun's comments, I decided to refactor the way I set up this function by putting it in my index.html's controller. It acts as a $rootscope since all my partial views inherit its $scope. I can then call the function as needed from whatever views need access to it.

Comment: Actually, after reading @Shaun's comment, I found it better from an implementation standpoint to abstract that function into a service. Then I just add the service to any controller that needs it and invoke it as necessary. Seems like the way I thought that directive feature was supposed to be used is not the way it should be used.

Comment: I was thinking you needed to do something similar to how videogular gives a reference to its API to the parent controller so the parent can control the video, not that you were pushing data around that wasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always write your directives as components that could be used in any app. They should not be providing data, they should be doing something with it. Your view controller should be providing data to your directive via a [two-way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/u1t0x9bu/)

### view1.html

```
<div ng-controller="View1Ctrl as vm">
  <h1>View1</h1>
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <div time-directive config="vm.data"></div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.model1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.model2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.data.model3">
    <button ng-click="vm.someFunction(vm.data)">Do Things</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

### view1.controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('View1Ctrl', View1Ctrl);

function View1Ctrl() {
  //Initializing directive data fields
  var ed = new Date();
  var dms = ed.getTime();
  var sd = new Date(dms - 1800000); //1,800,000ms = 30 min
  var vm = this;

  vm.data = {};
  vm.data.tkrIntrvl = 10;
  vm.data.refresh = 60;
  vm.data.startDate = sd;
  vm.data.endDate = ed;
  vm.data.startTime = sd;
  vm.data.endTime = ed;

  vm.someOtherObject = {};
  vm.someOtherObject.startDate = vm.data.startDate;
  vm.someOtherObject.endDate = vm.data.endDate;

  vm.someFunction = function(data) {
    // Do Things
  };
}
```

### time.directive.js

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('timeDirective', timeDirective);

function timeDirective() {
  return {
    bindToController: {
      data: '=config'
    },
    controller: 'TimeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/time.html'
  };
}
```

### time.controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('TimeCtrl', TimeCtrl);

function TimeCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
}
```

### time.directive.html

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.data.timeOptions" value="span">Time Span
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.data.timeOptions" value="ticker">Ticker
<fieldset ng-if="vm.data.timeOptions === 'span'">
  <label>Start:
    <input id="startDate" type="date" ng-model="vm.data.startDate">
    <input id="startTime" type="time" ng-model="vm.data.startTime">
  </label>
  <label>End:
    <input id="endDate" type="date" ng-model="vm.data.endDate">
    <input id="endTime" type="time" ng-model="vm.data.endTime">
  </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset ng-if="vm.data.timeOptions === 'ticker'">
  <label>Ticker Interval (min):
    <input class="ticker" type="number" step="1" ng-model="vm.data.tkrIntrvl">
  </label>
  <label>Refresh every (s):
    <input class="ticker" type="number" step="1" ng-model="vm.data.refresh">
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another issue. I mentioned I have functions as well as data in time.controller.js. I renamed those functions to vm.data.functionName = function() {}, and it does the trick, for the most part. However, I'm using angular ui-router to route to View1.html from another page with `$state.go()`. When I access View1.html via this method, and try to call a function within time.controller.js I keep getting the "[some function in time.controller.js] is not a function" error. I have the controllerAs property defined in my $stateprovider so I'm not sure what's wrong

Comment: TimeCtrl is your timeDirective's controller, you shouldn't be accessing it directly from your View1Ctrl. You can add event listeners to your timeDirective, so it can call its own controller functions based on certain user interactions. To do that, add a link function to the directive's definition object. The link function receives the following args: (scope, iElement, iAttrs, vm), where vm is the instance of TimeCtrl. So, scope.$on('click', function(event) { vm.handleClick(); }); in your link function would call a handleClick function in your TimeCtrl whenever the directive element is clicked.

Comment: You along with @Amy_Blankenship in the comment chain on my question both have mentioned that I shouldn't be accessing functions in the directive controller directly from View1Ctrl like that. The main reason I added the function to timeDirective's controller is because I have three different views that all use this directive as well as this function. I ended up putting this function in my index.html's controller which acts as a $rootscope since all my partial views inherit its $scope. I then call the function as needed, passing in the vm.data variables to it as arguments.

Comment: This function is never called via some event. It's always called within another function that's local to a particular view's controller like this: `function (View1Ctrl) { $scope.view1Function = function() { //...some code; //...more code; timeDirectiveCtrlFunction(); }; });`

Unless you can recommend me a better way of setting up timeDirectiveCtrlFunction so that it can be called from those different views, I'm going to stick with the method I went with in my previous comment and just mark your answer as the correct answer because you did in fact answer my original question.

Comment: If you have a function that is used in several views, consider making it a service that can be injected rather than creating a "global" variable in some parent controller. The benefit is, by injecting a service you have an _explicit_ dependency apposed to an _implicit_ dependency on the parent controller.

Comment: Thanks, I removed it from index.html's controller and created a service.
View1Ctrl (or any Ctrl that uses the function):

`function (View1Ctrl) { 
     $scope.view1Function = function() { 
             //...some code; 
             //...more code; 
             $scope.someVar = Svc.svcFunction(arg);
       }; 
});`

Service:

`app.factory('Svc', function() {
    function svcFunction(param) {
        //code that manipulates param;
        return param;
    }

  return {
      svcFunction : svcFunction
  }
});`